# Weird result for packed number multiplication in an enhancement

Tags: math, abap, packed

I am missing a part to solve my problem.
**If I do this operation :**

```
TYPES: ty_p2 TYPE p DECIMALS 2.
DATA: lv_test TYPE ty_p2.

lv_test = '100.00' * '3.00'.
```

**I got this result in a program (specific program) on debugger view :**

[image]

this is the actual result I expect.

**I got this result in a program (enhancement of a standard) on debugger view :**

[image]

it's not the right result it's as if it were 100*3000 and it doesn't take into account the comma of the right hand operator of the multiplication.

---

**How do you explain this ?**

Is there an instruction which applies to the context of the ABAP session and which can modify the interpretation of the packed number during a multiplication? Or do you know where it comes from?

Thanks !

Comment: Don't add code as screenshot. Screenshot codes cannot be copy-pasted.

Comment: Is the "Fixed point arithmetic" turned on? Most like not... SE38 => Display => Menü Goto => Attributes. Popup comes up. Checkbox Fixed point arithmetic

Comment: Thanks a lot Jozsef! , yeah that's the explanation !

I didnt know about that attribute and btw on abap docu it says its obsolete to uncheck this attribute... and it's disabled on a common standard program.

I thought recovering the value on field TRDIR FIXPT with sy-repid to make a special treatment on this... Unless we can retrieve the value otherwise :p ?

Comment: Standard programs I would leave alone, SAP will come out with a correction, if something  is not working properly in the standard. I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed point arithmetic is not checked for the program.

When you are in change mode in SE38 (or SE80), use Menü Goto => Attributes
[image]

A popup comes up the checkbox for "Fixed point arithmetic" has to be checked (bottom-right corner of the popup window):
[image]

Using F1 Help on the field gives detailed explanation:
[image]